# Disable dates older than today in DatePicker plugin

Tags: jquery

Im using [DatePicker](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2009/09/09/unobtrusive-date-picker-widget-v5) plugin for a project. But I want to Disable dates older than today .(User couldnt select the old dates)
My js is:

```
datePickerController.createDatePicker({
formElements:{"inp1":"d-ds-m-ds-Y"} });
```

In manual :`Both methods accept an Object that represents the dates or date ranges to disable.`
I couldnt disable the old days yet with many trial and error. Can you please show me any way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Edit:

```
datePickerController.setRangeLow("myElementID",$today);

datePickerController.setRangeHigh("myElementID",$old_dayes);
```

I want to set dynamic date in `("myElementID","20081201")` .
Date ranges : `$today` and `$old_days = 'dates older than $today'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [docu](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2009/09/09/unobtrusive-date-picker-widget-v5) (note: this is exactly the link you've posted!)

> Limiting date selection i.e. setting
>   date ranges
>
> The datePicker enables you to define
>   both a lower and upper limit for date
>   selection.
>
> To add a lower or upper limit, just
>   add the parameters “rangeHigh” and/or
>   “rangeLow” to the initialisation
>   object and set their values to be a
>   YYYYMMDD date format String; for
>   example, the following code will limit
>   date selection outside of the range
>   13/03/1970 to 20/12/1999:

```
var opts = {                            
  formElements:{"inp1":"d-sl-m-sl-Y"},
  // Set a range low of 13/03/1970                
  rangeLow:"19700313",
  // Set a range high of 20/12/2009
  rangeHigh:"20091220"                
};      
datePickerController.createDatePicker(opts);
```

for those, who are not willing to scroll (just one line down in the docu)...

> Setting the date range dynamically
>
> The upper and lower date ranges can
>   also be set programmatically by
>   calling the following two methods:

```
// Set the lower limit to be 01/12/2008
datePickerController.setRangeLow("myElementID","20081201");
// Set the upper limit to be 01/12/2009
datePickerController.setRangeHigh("myElementID","20091201");
```

**edit:**

html:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

javascript:

```
var today = new Date();
var options = {
    formElements: {
        "datepicker": "d-sl-m-sl-Y"
    },
    rangeLow: today.getFullYear() + today.getMonth() + today.getDay(),
};
datePickerController.createDatePicker(options);
```

Comment: I doesnt disable dates dynamically.

Comment: @Andreas; I know issues in manual. Above dates may be dynamic. $today and $datesolderthantoday that set dynamic. But Im not very familliar with js. My question is that how can set this date dynamically.

Comment: you may elaborate! what is `$tody` and `$datesolderthantody`? please support some code of what you've tried!

Answer (score 5):

For simple solution see: [this site](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1083/jquery-datepicker-disable-future-dates).
Fast & easy :)

```
 $(function () {
       var date = new Date();
       var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
       var currentDate = date.getDate();
       var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

       $('#YourDatepicker').datepicker({
            maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
       }); 
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

For a more simpler method than upiic's:

```
function () {
    $('#DatePickerControlName').datepicker({maxDate: 0}); 
});
```

NB. The 0 means zero days from now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering to disable old dates then try this.

```
$(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
        var currentDate = date.getDate();
        var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

        $('#validity_picker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
        });
    });
```